Converting a valid cbor string to cbor bytes
how do i convert a valid cbor that is in string to bytes?
cbor = "b'\xa1bip\x186'"
Using bytes or the usual stuff isnt working e.g .encode('utf-8')
I want to be able to use loads on the data
data = cbor2.loads(cbor)

From what I understand you want to convert a string into another of 0 and 1 which is the binary representation of the original string, you can use this code:
string = 'ciao'
binary_representation = ''.join([f'{byte:08b}' for byte in string.encode('utf-8')])
print(type(binary_representation), binary_representation)

To add a space between characters you can use:
binary_representation = ' '.join([f'{byte:08b}' for byte in string.encode('utf-8')])

Rember that "b'\xa1bip\x186'"'s type is byte, you can see it from the initial b.
